# How can I access values from a C union in Rust?

Tags: rust, unions

I'm trying to call the function `SDL_PollEvent` from the C library `SDL2`. I'm aware that there are already wrappers available, but I'd like to create my own, just for learning. The function expects a pointer to this C union:

```
typedef union{
  Uint8 type;
  SDL_ActiveEvent active;
  SDL_KeyboardEvent key;
  SDL_MouseMotionEvent motion;
  SDL_MouseButtonEvent button;
  SDL_JoyAxisEvent jaxis;
  SDL_JoyBallEvent jball;
  SDL_JoyHatEvent jhat;
  SDL_JoyButtonEvent jbutton;
  SDL_ResizeEvent resize;
  SDL_ExposeEvent expose;
  SDL_QuitEvent quit;
  SDL_UserEvent user;
  SDL_SysWMEvent syswm;
} SDL_Event;
```

I have imported the function like this:

```
#[link(name = "SDL2")]
extern "C" {
    fn SDL_PollEvent(event: *mut SdlEvent) -> libc::c_int;
}
```

And declared the type like this:

```
type SdlEvent = [u8; 56];
```

Now I can call `SDL_Pollevent` and retrieve the `type` value of the union:

```
// According to sizeof(SDL_Event), the unit is 56 bytes
let mut sdl_event: SdlEvent = [0; 56];

unsafe { SDL_PollEvent(&mut sdl_event) };

let event_type: u32 = u32::from_be((sdl_event[0] as u32) << 24 | (sdl_event[1] as u32) << 16 |
                                   (sdl_event[2] as u32) << 8 |
                                   (sdl_event[3] as u32));

match event_type {                              
    0x100 => {
        Event {                     
             // 0x100 is SDL_QUIT -> quit application
     }
    }                                      
    0x200 => {
        Event { // SDL_KEYDOWN
             // How can I 
     }
    }                                      
}
```

This works fine, but now I'd like to know which key has been pressed, which means I need to retrieve the value `key` of the type `SDL_KeyboardEvent`. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you aware of [unions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/36016) in Rust?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, I have read about that, but I'm not sure how I could use them to communicate with C functions. At the moment, I have been using the information from this tutorial: http://hermanradtke.com/2016/03/17/unions-rust-ffi.html

Comment: @MatthieuM. what am I missing with this union? Having the type be a part of the union seems very wrong to me; won't the type itself be written the the same memory as all the other union members?

Comment: @Shepmaster This works by including the ``type`` value into every struct type, e.g. see the definition of ``SDL_KeyboardEvent``: https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlkeyboardevent.html

Comment: @PhilippLudwig ah, I was just about to post to answer my own question! Silly C and fake-inheritance :-)

Comment: @Shepmaster: it's an artifact of the way struct are laid out in memory in C (and C++), basically if two types share a "prefix", then you can write one type in the union and read the fields of the prefix through the other. It's an exception to the regular lifetime rules.

Comment: Why are you reading `event_type` as 4-bytes when it's defined in C as a single byte?

Comment: Because it's actually uint32_t, I copied the wrong struct from SDL1 (I'm targeting SDL2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unions are basically exactly like C, which means they are unsafe to access. They are also an unstable feature as of Rust 1.16:

```
#![feature(untagged_unions)]

extern crate libc;

// Definitions for SDL_ActiveEvent, SDL_KeyboardEvent, etc.

#[repr(C)]
union SDLEvent {
    typ: libc::uint8_t,
    active: SDL_ActiveEvent,
    key: SDL_KeyboardEvent,
    // All the rest
}

fn thing(event: SDLEvent) {
    unsafe { 
        println!("{}", event.typ);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one follow-up question: Since they are unstable, would you recommend using unions or manually accessing the bytes like I did in my posted code?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig ultimately, it depends on your usecase. For most things I do, targeting nightly isn't a problem, so I'd use unions because I don't want to mess around with the low-level bitbanging unless I'm writing code for the AVR. If you have to / choose to target stable, then your answer is made for you ^_^

Comment: Thanks! Since I'm just learning, I will be playing around with the rust unions :)